# Replace max and min, second max and second min and so on in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to invert it in a sense that I want to swap max and min, second max and second min and so on.

```py
arr = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4]
# Output should be [4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1]

arr = [4, 4, 1, 2]
# Output should be [1, 1, 4, 2]
```

Is there a way to vectorize this?

Comment: With `[4, 4, 1, 2]`, which one is the "first maximum" and which one is the "second maximum"? Is the result `[1, 2, 4, 4]` or `[2, 1, 4, 4]`? Your specification is incomplete, IMHO

Comment: I would want [1, 1, 4, 2]

Comment: @ThomasWeller The first and second maximum are considered to be in terms of unique values in the set. I added your example in problem. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If the ith min is replaced with the (n-i)th max (ith starting from the end), then why the third 1 is not replaced by 3 since the sorted values are `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]` ? Can you please describe the algorithm further? Are the value themselves replaced?

Comment: @JérômeRichard: that's what I stumbled upon as well. I think he wants unique values, so [1, 2, 3, 4] maps to [4, 3, 2, 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to swap the unique values, you can use **`np.unique`** to get both the *sorted* unique values and the index of the selected unique value in the sorted unique value. Then, you can **revert** the array of unique values to swap the min and max values. After that, the *index will reference swapped min-max values*, so you can just extract them using and **indirect indexing**. Here is the resulting **fully vectorized code**:

```py
arr = np.array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4])
uniqueItems, ids = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)
out = uniqueItems[::-1][ids]
# out: [4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can at least be partially vectorized:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4])
uniques = np.unique(data)
mapping = np.dstack((uniques, np.flip(uniques)))[0]
result = np.copy(data)
for key, value in mapping:
    result[data == key] = value
print(result)
```

Output is as expected:

```
[4 3 4 2 3 1 4 1]
```